# react router onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

How to pass new props when route changed? 
I need change class depends on route.

```
export class Routes extends React.Component<any, any> {
constructor(props:any){
    super(props);
}
handleChange = (prevState, nextState, replaceState) => {
    console.log(nextState.location.pathname);
};
render(){
    return(
        <Router {...this.props}>
            <Route  path="/" onChange={this.handleChange} component={Miramir}>
                <Route  path="/about">
                    <IndexRoute component={Miramir}></IndexRoute>
                </Route>
                <Route  path="/contact">
                    <IndexRoute component={Miramir}></IndexRoute>
                </Route>
                <Route path="/profile">
                    <IndexRoute component={Profile} />
                    <Route path="/profile/update" component={ProfileUpdate} />
                    <Route path="/profile/login" component={LogInPage} />
                </Route>
            </Route>
        </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

I'm trying to get props in my Miramir component and check `location.pathname`

For example: On my route / i want header class `home-page` and on /profile route want `profile-page` class. 
But when i change routes `location.pathname` has `/` route

How to check update props?

I need `nextState.location.pathname` in my Miramir component

Comment: not sure if this can help you browserHistory.listen( location =>  {//Do your stuff here}); here based on path you can do your code

Answer (score 1):

You can provide `onEnter` hook when route is about to change.

e.g

```
 <Route 
     path="/profile/update" 
     component={ProfileUpdate} 
     onEnter={onProfileUpdate}
 />
```

Then you can define that function `onProfileUpdate`

```
function onProfileUpdate(nextState, replace, callback) {

   replace({
        pathname: '/transition path name here',
        state: { nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname }
    });

}
```

Comment: Is there a way to pass `nextState.location.pathname` when it changed to my Miramir component? 
your solution is not waht i need :) 
Thanks for help

Comment: @АндрейГузюк yes you can pass that in the similar way you just use the onEnter hook for index route. nextPathname will be available in your component's state.

Answer (score 0):

If your component is a route component, like it is in your case, it will get some props injected into it by the Router itself. You'll get your current location, params and so on, so you could simply read that in your `render` method and act accordingly.

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#injected-props

If you need to access something in a component living deeper in your tree, you could wrap it with the `withRouter` HOC.

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#withroutercomponent-options